# Therefore instead of equals, theta instead of plus, Lambda instead of minus? Odd notation.

Tags: notation

I ran into some strange notation in [Goldstein et al. (2002)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1207/S15328031US0104_02), and I was wondering what the story behind it is (e.g. where else I might find such notation, what is the point of it...).

The authors use $\therefore$ instead of $=$, a cursive $\theta$ instead of $+$, and $\Lambda$ instead of minus.

[image]

Comment: [This](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/media-library/sites/cmm/migrated/documents/variance-partitioning.pdf) version of the paper doesn't seem to have weird notation. I think you might be reading a glitched version.

Comment: Thanks. In that version you found a chart has also been corrected. So maybe these are just misprints like you said.

Comment: @JackM you can post that comment as an answer and I will accept it. Or should I just delete the question? I don't think it will be useful to anyone else. Not sure what the proper procedure is here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/media-library/sites/cmm/migrated/documents/variance-partitioning.pdf) version of the paper doesn't seem to have weird notation. I think you might be reading a glitched version.